# download multiple files from http using webclient

Tags: .net, vb.net, download, webclient

I am trying to download multiple json files to local directory but not getting it able to work. The file seems to be empty. I know the url works as when I paste in the browser I get the list of urls to the file.

```
        wclient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
        wclient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
        wclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(url), "C:\Users\Files\" & 
          "archivefile_" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString & ".json")
```

this is the response when pasting into a browser;

```
"urlList":[
            "https://archive.amazonaws.com/original/
     results1.json.gz?...",
      "https://archive.amazonaws.com/original/
     results2.json.gz?...",
```

any ideas appreciated.

Comment: ok I took one of the individual data urls and tried to download the individual file but then got error message 403 forbidden. Am using required credentials

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The error message 403 was simply due to the url being snipped off and missing the end parameters. Works now.